# Союзы "и" в моём примере повторяющиеся или играют разную роль?

Tags: пунктуация

> И гуляли мы там, и гуляли. Весь день прогуляли. Я даже в вечерний
>   прямой эфир чуть не опоздала. Всё ходила и рассказывала ему, какая я
>   молодец. **И сколько я всего делаю, и сколько всего успеваю.** Он был
>   ко мне очень внимателен, а в конце концов спросил: «Слушай, а тебе всё
>   это очень надо?»

От вашего ответа зависит (сдаётся мне) быть запятой вовнутрях иль не быть.

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Запятая нужна в любом случае,** так как союз И...И повторяющийся. Интонация перечислительная.